# Чи має право на життя слово торкатися?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи можна вживати слово торкатися у даному випадку?

> "Не зважаючи на плин часу ми не можемо не торкатися цієї дуже гострої
>   теми"

Бо як на мене то "стосуватися" не дуже пасує. 
Ця стаття розміщена у блозі.

Answer (score 6):

Тут «торкатися» вжито **абсолютно коректно**.

## Обмеження, пов'язанні зі словом «торкатися»

Зрозумійте, саме слово «торкатися» ніхто не забороняв. Просто воно, на думку багатьох, має вужчу множину значень, ніж російське «касаться». Наприклад, ми можемо сказати:

1. «Він ніжно її торкнувся».
   <sup>Рос. «он нежно её коснулся».</sup>
   Тобто значення прямого фізичного дотику.

Або ще можна сказати:

2. «Я торкнувся цієї теми у вчорашній розмові».
   <sup>Рос. «я коснулся этой темы во вчерашнем разговоре».</sup>

   Тобто більш переносне значення «дотику». Вживається у значенні «звертати на щось увагу в розмові/думках» (тобто говорити/думати про щось).

Але річ у тім, що в російського «касаться» є ще одне значення — воно може вживатися замість нашого «стосуватися»:

3. Рос. «меня это не касается!»
   <sup>«Мене це не стосується!»</sup>

   Це вже інше значення порівняно з другим. Тут ми кажемо про наявність/відсутність зв'язку з чимось, а не про те, що воно було обговорено/обмислено у якійсь бесіді/роздумах.

Дехто і в третьому випадку вживає слово «торкатися». Мені особисто це дуже ріже слух. І припускаю, що багатьом іншим теж. Хоча «Словник української мови» в 11 томах і каже, що слову «торкатися» це значення теж властиве — але мені суб'єктивно важко в це повірити. Припускаю, через те й з'явилися перестороги щодо слова «торкатися», які Ви, мабуть, не зовсім правильно зрозуміли.

## «Торкатися» vs. «стосуватися»

Якщо різниця між найчастішими значеннями слова «торкатися» і «стосуватися» не зрозуміла з попередньої частини, то, сподіваюся, все роз'яснить такий приклад:

> У вчорашній бесіді ми торкнулися теми створення сприятливих умов для малого бізнесу. Було дуже цікаво про це поговорити, хоч мене особисто це і не стосується, адже я не бізнесмен.

Тобто:

- Я торкнувся теми бізнесу (я говорив зокрема про неї).
- Але ані я її не стосуюся, ані вона мене не стосується (я не маю з нею зв'язку).

## Синоніми до «торкатися»

В значенні, обговорюванному у питанні, слово «торкатися» еквівалентне слову «зачіпати». Дехто може вважати одне з них росіянізмом, але вони обидва мають прямий російський еквівалент (тож яке з них ближче до російської мови — встановити важко):

- «Я торкнувся теми податків».
  <sup>Рос. «я коснулся темы налогов».</sup>
- «Я зачепив тему податків».
  <sup>Рос. «я затронул тему налогов».</sup>

Є й такі майже-синоніми:

- «піднімати» («я підняв тему податків»);
- «порушити» («я порушив тему податків»).

Але вони мають трішки інші значення. «Порушити тему» — безпосередньо почати говорити про щось, що часто передбачає більші прямоту і ступінь залучення, ніж «просто трішечки торкнутися теми». «Підняти тему» означає спроковувати обговорення якоїсь теми — що теоретично можна зробити, самому її навіть не торкаючись.

## Див. також

- «Торкатися — стосуватися — відноситися» в [«Уроках рержавної мови» Бориса Рогози (газета «Хрещатик»)](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/181.htm).
- Цієї теми трішки торкнулися у [цій гілці на Лінгвофорумі](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=71597.75).